# Derivative visual meaning

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

Edit: I figured out on my own but here is question:

Question: Find the visual meaning  of the numerator of: 
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$

---

So, I found this: [image]

Is this how the graph looks like?

Comment: Edit rolled back because it made the Question incoherent.

Answer (score 3):

It is closely related to the length of the vertical segment from $(x,f(x))$ to $(x,L(x))$ where $L$ is the secant line between $(x-h,f(x-h))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$. This like the second derivative is a measure of deviation from linearity near $x$.

Comment: I sort of see what you are saying.  So how exactly is it related to the length of this vertical segment?.  Is the picture I posted below at all related?  Thanks

Comment: @kemb The picture shows an $f$ and an $L$ so yes it is related. To see the connection explicitly just compute $L(x)-f(x)$.

Comment: The thing that I am confused by how does the first difference line segment differ from the second difference ?  I don't completely get it, really want to understand.

Comment: @kemb The first centered difference is proportional to the slope of the secant line $L$. The second centered difference is proportional to the difference $L(x)-f(x)$.

Comment: I see that makes more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: So I've been still been thinking about the question.  I found this picture:

Comment: I posted the picture below.  So based on the graph, the second difference is still proportional to the difference between the secant line and f(x)?  Last question, thanks.